# What a kooky association

Tags: knowledge, poetry

One evokes pizza
One fuzzy, maybe funny
Spooks, fruit or pork, frog
Double letters (in Japan?)
Two known names; link them to solve
Bonus: This poem has link, too

**Hint 1:**

> All lines apply to
>  two characters in my mind.
>  Although both are in
>  entertainment, only one
>  renown in video games.

**Hint 2:**

> Spelling clue somewhere,
>  but answers' forms could vary.
>  How they sound matter the most.

<sub>Warming up for a puzzle inspired by this fortnight's theme... Don't worry; it would not be more of my awful poems.</sub>

Comment: I have a feeling it's about pokemon?  However I do know know enough to provide an answer

Comment: @Alex Nope, no Pokemon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the characters are:

> Pacman and Fozzy bear from the Muppet Show

Because

> pacman is shaped like a pizza with a slice missing
>  Fozzy is fuzzy, and is a lame comedian
>  pacman deals with ghosts and fruit, fozzy has Ms Piggy and Kermit (pork  and frog)
>  In japanese, pacman is sometimes spelled Pakkuman
>  The link: they both go Wakka-wakka!

Comment: Correct! Thanks for saving me from having to do another [waka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waka_(poetry)) hint, which explains the "bonus" line. You got enough lines to earn the check.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I suspect so far, but it's a bit kooky/incomplete at places:

> These are all Super Smash Bros 4 characters

One evokes pizza

> My best bet so far is Wario, since in the WarioWare series, there is a character Mona Pizza that sells...well you get it. There's also a song on WarioWare stage called "Mona Pizza's Song"

One fuzzy, maybe funny

> This one I don't get. At first I thought Donkey Kong/Diddy Kong, but the clue implies it's a single character.

Spooks

> Pacman & ghost co.

fruit or pork

> Here I think this is Mr. Game & Watch. I haven't played him in SSB4, but in brawl, it was difficult to tell if what he was flinging in his neutral B was bacon or fish or what. Also one of his Side-B results (7, I think?) drops a healing fruit.

frog

> Greninja is a frog Pokemon

Double letters (in Japan?)

> There are a couple characters with double letters, but the Japan clue makes me more certain that it's Wii Fit Trainer (where Villager would not have double--or single--L in it's Japanese rendition and Wii is the Japanese name for the console)

Two known names; link them to solve

> This was the clue that started it off for me, this seems to hint at Zelda and her alter ego Sheik. The inclusion of the word link reinforces this.

Bonus: This poem has link, too

> Link himself is also a character in the game

Comment: +1 for attempt (and for reminding me of good gaming times), and you did get one of the names. I'm going to update my question with a clarification hint that this puzzle is about just two characters and I'm looking for what these two have in common.